# Thread will not close, doesn't seem to reach changed variable

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, unity-game-engine

I am working on a multiplayer game, using the `lidgren` library for networking.

I am currently having issues with a my function that reads messages sent from my server.
The function looks like this:

```
public class Client
{
    /* code omitted */

    public void ReadMessage()
    {   
        //Read Messages
        while (running)
        {
        Debug.Log("InREAD");
           //wClient is a NetClient (lidgren library)
        NetIncomingMessage msg;
        while ((msg = wClient.ReadMessage()) != null)
        {

            switch (msg.MessageType)
            {
                case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:

                    if (msg.ReadString().Contains("Position"))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Hej");
                        /*string temp = msg.ReadString();
                    string[] Parts = temp.Split(" ");

                    int x = int.Parse(Parts [1]);
                    int y = int.Parse(Parts [2]);
                    int z = int.Parse(Parts [3]);*/


                        //set player position to xyz values below
                    } else if (msg.ReadString().Contains("Instantiate"))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Instantiate");
                        /* string temp = msg.ReadString();
                        string[] Parts = temp.Split(" ");*/

                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, there is a while-loop that runs when the bool running is true (and yes I am setting it as true when declaring.).

Now, in my GUI class where the button for connecting is etc, I have a function call to `OnApplicationQuit` which looks like this:

```
void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    client.running = false;
    client.Disconnect();
    Debug.Log(client.running);
    Debug.Log("Bye");
}
```

However, the change of running doesn't reach the thread (I believe the thread is running on a cached version of the variable?). So my question is, how do i make the while-loop stop when the program is closed? (Ive tried calling on the `.Abort()` function on the thread in the `OnApplicationQuit()`, but it doesn't work either.

Also, i know its not very efficient to send strings over a network unless you need to (so no need telling me about that!)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing (since I do not know library `lidgren`): isn't it possible that you're thread is stuck in call `wClient.ReadMessage()` just because you are not receiving any message from the client? If `wClient.ReadMessage()` is a blocking call then the resulting behaviour would be the one you described.

Furthermore: even calling `Thread.Abort()` won't work because the thread is in a sleep state (since it is waiting for something coming from the network connection): the thread will be aborted as soon as your `wClient.ReadMessage()` returns. Looking MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/5b50fdsz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it tells that "*If Abort is called on a managed thread while it is executing unmanaged code, a ThreadAbortException is not thrown until the thread returns to managed code*" and this exactly your situation assuming that `ReadMessage()` at some point will perform a system call just to wait for some data coming from the underlying socket.

Comment: Shouldn't the disconnect call interrupt the ReadMessage function?

Comment: @ThaMe90: I don't know... as said I do not know how `lidgren` and the answer to your questions depends on how `ReadMessage()` has been implemented in `lidgren`

Answer (score 0):

You must call `client.Shutdown()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Oops, you are correct; I did not read the question thoroughly enough. NetClient.ReadMessage() does not block however, and calling Shutdown() should be done when exiting the application (as it will end the networking thread).